# drawRoundRect differents radius for each corner

Tags: android

I would like to draw a square with differents corner radius, for example the top with a "25px" radius and the bottom not rounded.

My current `code` (all the corner have the same radius)

```
c.drawRoundRect(
tmpDrawHalf, // rect
cornersRadius, // rx
cornersRadius, // ry
paint // Paint
);
```

How to achieve that ?

EDIT:
My goal:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCu2f.png)

Comment: use `android.graphics.Path`

Comment: You can also use layer list drawable to make the shape and just draw the Drawable in your View.

Comment: @Ali layer list drawable? what for? if you want to use a drawable then just use `GradientDrawable` / `PaintDrawable` and their method `setCornerRadii`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a drawable to make the shape you want.
Then draw the shape in your View.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="25dp" android:topRightRadius="25dp"  />
        </shape>
```

Then in your `onDraw` method. You can even use this method to add different states for pressed, disabled etc by using a selector drawable.

```
Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.***)
d.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom); 
d.draw(canvas);
```

Answer (score 0):

your **activity_main.xml** just define your view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.softeng.drawshape.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/recta"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

now create drawable file name `recta.xml` in my case and set it to background of your `ImageView`.

**recta.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <padding
        android:top="3dp"
        android:left="8dp"
        android:right="8dp"
        android:bottom="3dp"/>

    <solid android:color="#E6121A" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="25dp"
        android:topRightRadius="25dp" />

</shape>
```

**Output :**

[image]